# Activate ':hover' only when mouse moves down list and remove when mouse moves up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have to implement a Jquery function in which every `li` Element is executing the `:hover` pseudo class (which only changes the background color). So if I hover down to the 4th Element ALL previous `li` Elements (1st, 2nd, 3th) should have the changed background color from the `:hover` pseudo class!! But if I move up with the mouse again the `:hover` effect should disappear (normal background color again) up to the point where my mouse is (if it is on 2nd element only 1st and 2nd have the hover effect now) ... I have absolutely no idea how I can create such a method... I did something like

```
$('ul li').on('mouseenter') { 
$(this).addClass('hover'); //alternatively $(this).css('background-color', 'grey'); 
}
```

but it does not remove any `:hover` effect and it makes failures possible like that only the first and the 5th `li` Element have the `:hover` effect but all in between remain normal which I don't want... Could you please help me?

Comment: Try `.toggleClass('hover');`

Comment: That might work if I want them to be random... but cases where only e.g. the first and last li elements have the hover class should not be allowed... there has to be some kind of if condition where I can check if that li Element is far more down the list than the previously toggled li element.. and then :hover them all up to that point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Link to working example on jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/b8hg5u0a/)

---

So lets start with some sample markup for a list:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Then some css for your 'hover':

```
.hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

And some javascript to give the functionality:

```
$(function(){

    // Our list items.
    var listItems = $('ul').children();

    // An event listener over all list items.
    $('li').hover(hoverIn, hoverOut);

    // Find the index of the current element
    // and set all elements up to this element as hover.
    function hoverIn() {
       var index = listItems.index(this);
       $.each(listItems, function(idx, ele) {
          if (idx <= index) {
              $(this).addClass('hover');
          } else {
              $(this).removeClass('hover');
          }
       });
    }

    // Remove all hover.
    function hoverOut() {
      $.each(listItems, function(idx, ele) {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
      });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact this could be done entirely with css. No jQuery or JavaScript is required for this. You should consider using some html structure like this:

```
<ul>
   <li><span>Menu item 1</span></li>
   <li>
      <span>Menu item 2</span>
      <ul>
         <li><span>Submenu item 1</span></li>
         <li>
            <span>Submenu item 2</span>
            <ul>
               <li><span>Subsubmenu item 1</span></li>
               <li><span>Subsubmenu item 2</span></li>
               <li><span>Subsubmenu item 3</span></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><span>Submenu item 3</span></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Then you can use css like this

```
li:hover > span {
    background: #9a0000;
}
```

See this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aey5cusm/

Or if you ment by first, second, thirth of a single list, it can be done with css too.

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul:hover li {
  background: #9a0000;
}

li:hover ~ li{
  background: none;
}
```

Just look at this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aey5cusm/1/